# The difference between undefined and optional declaration

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, what is the difference between

```
interface something {
    foo?:  string;
}
```

versus

```
interface something {
    foo: string | undefined;
}
```

The same applies to function parameters, which can be decorated with a ? or declared with an `undefined` option.

Update:  The comment below points to an answer which I believe is inadequate or I missed something.   What that answer says is that the second interface example above *always* has a property `foo` in it which can take on the value `undefined`.

Rather than actually *being* undefined.  The Typescript spec says the following are identical:

```
foo?:  string
foo?:  string | undefined
```

but then why is that different from:

```
foo: string | undefined
```

I guess what is not explained anywhere is why have both `null` and `undefined` values?

Comment: When you add a tag for Typescript, you don't need to also use it in the title. The tag makes it clear that the question is about Typescript.

Comment: @MattU not really.   In fact that answer brings up more questions, such as the relationship between null and undefined.